# Powershell error when deleting old files and folders

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete some old files in an archive folder and my script works fine until it gets to the last section where it removes the empty folders (testing using `-whatif` initially). I get the following error:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\ArchiveDelete.ps1:13 char:39
+   $dirs | Foreach-Object { Remove-Item <<<<  $_.fullname -whatif }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Tried to find a suitable answer on here but can't find a solution (I know I may be using an older version of Powershell)

```
#Days older than
$HowOld = -900

#Path to the root folder
$Path = "C:\SharedWorkspace\ArchiveDSAgile"

#Deletion files task
get-childitem $Path -recurse | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays($HowOld) -and -not $_.psiscontainer} |% {remove-item $_.fullname -force -whatif}

#Deletion empty folders task
do {
  $dirs = gci $Path -recurse | Where { (gci $_.fullName -Force).count -eq 0 -and $_.PSIsContainer } | select -expandproperty FullName
  $dirs | Foreach-Object { Remove-Item $_ -whatif }
} while ($dirs.count -gt 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of your loops are necessary.

You can feed the output of `Where-Object` right into `Remove-Item`

```
$AgeCap = (Get-Date).AddDays(-900)
$Path = "C:\SharedWorkspace\ArchiveDSAgile"

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -File | Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt $AgeCap | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

The `-File` parameter for `Get-ChildItem` available in PowerShell 3.0 (I believe) and higher. The Workaround for PowerShell 2.0 would be checking against `$_.PSIsContainer` in `Where-Object`, as you did in your sample code.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your help - with your code I'm now getting:

Comment: Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.
At line:4 char:35
+ Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -File <<<<  | Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt $AgeCap | Remove-Item -WhatIf
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: What's your PowerShell version? Use `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()` to find out.

Comment: PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
2.0

Comment: That version is more than 10 years old now. Consider updating PowerShell to something more recent. If that's not an option, you need to go back to the `$_.PSIsContainer` check you had originally.

Comment: Unfortunately this machine is operationally critical so I don't want to start updating stuff - Do you have the correct syntax for using $_.PSIsContainer in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working:

```
#Days older than
$HowOld = -900

#Path to the root folder
$Path = "C:\SharedWorkspace\ArchiveDSAgile"

#Deletion files task
get-childitem $Path -recurse | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays($HowOld) -and -not $_.psiscontainer} |% {remove-item $_.fullname -force -whatif}

#Deletion empty folders task
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays($HowOld) -and -not !$_.psiscontainer} | Remove-Item -recurse -WhatIf
```

Thanks for your help